# How to test addEventListener in Mocha/Chai/Sinon with vanillajs and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have an issue with Mocha testing an eventlistener that checks for input.
My environment is with plain javascript, nodejs and mocha/chai/sinon for testing.
I wrote some other tests that are working, basically checking functions but the test hits on "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".

Since I'm quite new to testing I've dug around in the documentation, added JSDOM and such but no luck. I simply don't know how to check for the eventlistener. Many of the threads already available are React environments which seem to have some sort of built in applications that helps them, but not me.

So it's basically this, really narrowed down:

```
const userInput = document.querySelector("#userInfo");
userInput.addEventListener("input", changeContent);
```

It checks for user input and in the changeContent method it just checks for length etc.
Any takers on how I should do this?

**Edit:**
Slight workaround that "skips" my issue, but it would be nice to learn how to solve it in a test anyway. With this the test passes (because it ignores it).

Workaround, since the test points eventListener to null:

```
if(userInput){
  userInput.addEventListener("input", changeContent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `spy` to test if `addEventListener` is getting called. There is no specific reason to test the implementation of `addEventListener`.

Also you have to fake the `document.querySelector` and force it to return an HTMLElement.

**Long story short:**

Use spy for `addEventListener`: https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/spies/

Use fakes for `document.querySelector`: https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/

**Example of spy for** `console.log`:

```
// method implementend in your project
function log() {
   console.log('Hello world');

}

// log.spec.ts

...
describe('whatever test suite', () => {
    it('test log', () => {
        const consoleSpy = Sinon.spy(console, 'log');
        log();

        Sinon.assert.calledWith(consoleSpy, 'Hello world');
    });
});
...
```

Comment: Oh, I've learnt more from that than 4 hours of documentations, thanks!
I still have some issues wrapping my head around how I would check if addEventListener is being called. Tried to set up a fake but seems like I failed there as well, everything points to using fakes with functions. "Connection" with log() in the test and in the actual file is working as expected though.

Comment: Would it be something just as easy as
const fake = sinon.fake.lookup.testing


where "lookup" is the project template...?

Comment: you don't have to pass the template

Comment: you have to for `getElementById` to return a HTMLElement object. You can create it directly in javascript

Comment: Ok, not pass template. Got it. So I don't need to reference to the template at all, even for the fake? Or would I create the fake FROM the template but then only reference to the fake in the test suite?

Also need to change querySelector to getElementById for it to work?

Comment: yes. You have to fake those methods. Please read this article for more information https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js

Comment: Read it a couple of times now but doesn't make it much clearer to me I'm afraid. Still no clue on how to fake the eventListener. :/

Comment: Added an edit to my original post, got a workaround but would still like to learn how to actually solve it if you have any more tips and tricks @Andrei Todorut